# PHP - Check if global class exists inside namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

How can you check if a global class exists with class_exists if you are inside the namespace of another class? For example:

```
<?php
namespace Rvdv\Test\Example;

class ExampleClass
{
    public function testNamespace()
    {
        // This says that it doesn't exists :(
        print class_exists('\\Test');
    }
}
```

Where class is a global defined class.

Comment: I am not sure I do understand Your problem... Could You explain more precisely, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've had to screw up something in your other issues - most likely the class test is not declared in this scope (did you forget include?). I tested this thusly:

phpcltest2.php:

```
<?php
class Test { }
```

phpcltest.php:

```
<?php
namespace Rvdv\Test\Example;
require 'phpcltest2.php';

class ExampleClass
{
    public function testNamespace()
    {
    print class_exists('\\Test');
    }
}

$nc = new ExampleClass();
$nc->testNamespace();
```

The results were expected: it prints out "1". So check your include paths.

Comment: It was indeed another issue. The guy who wrote the include script, named the function Test(). So I thought, seeing the capital, that it was a class and not a function. I replaced class_exists to function_exists and everything works as expected.Thanks for your help!