# Can't instanciate dynamic class

Tags: php

This is puzzling me. Why does the first line work and when I create the object dynamically it doesn't?

```
$a = new Strategy\NotificationStrategy(); // This works

$className = "Strategy\\NotificationStrategy";
var_dump(class_exists($className)); // bool(false)
$strategy = new $className(); // Fatal error: Class 'Strategy\NotificationStrategy' not found, etc..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725315/php-check-if-global-class-exists-inside-namespace

Comment: dude, I think your code should be: `$className = "Strategy\NotificationStrategy";` not `"double-slashes" //`

Comment: `class_exists` seems to handle correctly namespace, working example is `echo (class_exists("com::richardsumilang::common::MyClass")) ? "Yes" : "No";` Try with :: instead of \\ in your string.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a namespace declaration somewhere on top of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces resolves on compilation time. When you trying create object from string you must define absolute path of class. Something like this:

```
$className = "\\Vendor\\Package\\Strategy\\NotificationStrategy";
```

or

```
$className = __ NAMESPACE __."\\Strategy\\NotificationStrategy";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I tried something similar to what you did:

strategy.php:

```
<?php
    namespace Strategy{

      class NotificationStrategy{
        public function hello(){ echo "Hi!\n"; }
      }
    }
?>
```

instantiate.php

```
<?php
  require 'strategy.php';

  $ns    = new Strategy\NotificationStrategy();
  $klass = "Strategy\\NotificationStrategy";
  $qq    = new $klass();

  $qq->hello(); // Hi!
?>
```

This worked for me just fine, so if you're having problems, that leads me to think that you've got require issues...perhaps your dynamic call is trying to fire before the include for the file that contains the class definition?